# Analyzer ignoring certain word when used in Sklearn Tfidf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

Here is my code:

```
def ngrams(string, n=4):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD',r'', string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    R = [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
    if len(R) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        return R

L = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'a', 'aa', 'aaa']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 0, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b', analyzer=ngrams)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(L)

print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

The output of vocabulary is `{'a': 0}`.

I am confused where are `"aa"` and `"aaa"` and when you check my ngrams function, I am returning string if it's length is less then the parameter (which is 4 in above code).

The token regex is also made in a way to accept single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a theory.

I believe `TfidVectorizer` expects the `analyzer` function to return a sequence.  Notice the inputs vs outputs of your `ngrams` function:

```
'a'  -> 'a'
'aa' -> 'aa'
'aaa' -> 'aaa'
'aaaa' -> ['aaaa']
'aaaaa' -> ['aaaa','aaaa']
```

A string is a sequence, so in the first 3 cases, you are returning a sequence that consists of repeats of the single letter `'a'`.

If my theory is correct, you need to replace

```
        return string
```

with

```
        return [string]
```

Comment: It Worked!! Now I got it, Yes it require a sequence, and my function was giving a string, In my case there are 6 
( length of L)  documents so sequence of each document is required